# Vagrant, Ember-cli, Windows 8.1, Ubuntu. Livereload doesn't work! It doesn't detect changes when I save from Windows

Tags: ember.js, vagrant, ember-cli, livereload, watchman

I have this **VagrantFile**:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Use Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 64-bit as our operating system
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Configurate the virtual machine to use 2GB of RAM
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  # Forward the Rails server default port to the host
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 4200, host: 4200
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 35729, host: 35729
```

Everything works good, in my Windows I can visit `http://localhost:4200` and it works. But, there is a big but.

**I have the ember's project files in a Windows folder shared with vagrant.**

If I save files of my ember's project in Windows I can't have livereload, and  in my `vagrant ssh` I even can't view the changes detected.

If I go with `vagrant ssh` and use `nano application.hbs` and then save something new it detect changes and livereload works in my Chrome's window on Windows.

What the hell is the problem?

Comment: your ember's project is shared with vagrant ?

Comment: @FredericHenri, Yes, I have the ember's project files in a Windows folder shared with vagrant.

Comment: you should show the conf, are you using rsync ? its not clear when you say you make changes on windows, you dont see them from VM. try create a new file on windows, is it available on VM ? same when you work form VM do you see changes on windows

Comment: @FredericHenri, i'm not using rsync, i'm using the simple configuration of Vagrant. If I modify a file with vi or nano or other editor in `vagrant ssh` it works. Livereload (with eatchman) detects changes. If I modify in the same directory a file with Notepad or Sublimetext or other editors from Windows (in the same directory shared with vagrant) it doesn't detect anything and so livereload doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way Vagrant syncs directories between your desktop and the VM will break the default mechanism ember-cli uses to watch files and cause issues when updates are subsequently compiled.

To restore this functionality, you can either add the following lines to the '.ember-cli' file

```
"liveReload": true,
"watcher": "polling"
```

or invoke the serve command using the fallback polling watcher.

```
ember serve --watcher polling
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may help you: http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#usage-with-vagrant

Seems like you didn't fallback to polling watcher.

And you didn't also use NFS since it's not in your config. For windows user, you should use the [winnfsd plugin](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd) and install with `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that with this: `ember serve --watcher polling`. NFS sharing with Vagrant doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you please mark it as correct? I removed the part about NFS.

Comment: This is probably not very efficient but is a nice workaround to overcome virtualbox shares problem.